# Pass a string to the command line

Tags: python, command-line

I wrote some code that can search through a large csv file and, based on the search parameters, find a computer name.

Now, I would like to pass this string(computer name) along as a command-line parameter and automatically run RealVNC (located in `C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe`) with it. So, after the code is executed, RealVNC window will pop up and the computer on the network will be accessed remotely.

Comment: use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) and sys.argv

Comment: And maybe also check what parameters are accepted by vncviewer.exe on the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subprocess like this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["appname", "arguments"])
```

In case you don't have it, here's a [manual page](http://www.realvnc.com/products/open/4.1/man/vncviewer.html) for the command line arguments and their options.

Comment: The call method blocks the calling process until the child process is finished...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! However, RealVNC window comes up only after I close my program. Can I implement something simple like what you just gave me and run RealVNC right away?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I included your two lines in my while loop and that did the trick. Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module (and more specifically `call` or `Popen`)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), unless you want the calling program to wait for realvnc to exit...

```
import subprocess

hostname = 'foo.example.com' # Read the hostname from your CSV file instead.

# Suppres terminal windows on MS windows.
startupinfo = None
if os.name == 'nt':
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe', hostname])
```